# Style every thing except first child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know of the selector `:not()` but it doesn't work, like `tr:not(tr:first-child):hover`. I want to style the other `tr`s but not the first one, because it holds the headings. How can I do this without using an `id` or `class`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) in `:not()`, try

```
tr:not(:first-child)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/Sn7Uw/

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use the [`th` element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/th) which is specifically represents the header cell in a table.

#### Example

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>element</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>4.1.1</td>
      <td>html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.2.1</td>
      <td>head</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The other two answers are clever but this is semantically accurate

Comment: @thgaskell this doesn't allow for the row to be styled easily

Comment: `th { /* rules */ }` is too difficult?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators). As a bonus, it's a bit more widely supported than `:not()`

```
TR + TR { background-color: silver; }
TR + TR:hover { background-color: green; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ETYQN/2/

Answer (score 0):

Put your headers in a `<thead>` and your stylable rows in the `<tbody>` then use:

```
tbody tr:hover { background: red }
```

and it won't matter what the contents is.

http://jsfiddle.net/stevemarvell/we4a6/