# CSS : selecting multiple nth-child

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have this css :

```
div div p:nth-child(1),
div div p:nth-child(2),
div div p:nth-child(3),
div div p:nth-child(4),
div div p:nth-child(5) {
}
```

This will select nth-child elements from 1 until 5.

And here are shortcuts

```
div div p:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+5){
}
```

OR

```
div div p:nth-child(-n+5){
}
```

---

My question is,

How to select not the **first** element from 1 to 5, but the **second** element from 2 to 5 ?

So basically if I have this HTML :

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like it to apply a css background-color: red, only from the **second** div > p, and this until the 5th one.

Comment: _"How to select not the first element from 1 to 5, but the second element from 1 to 5?"_ - can you rephrase that or give an actual example, because I can't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: So you actually mean from 2 to 5 instead of 1 to 5.

Comment: Indeed Trincot, my bad.

Comment: For this specific case you could just add a `:not(first)` logic.

Comment: _"So basically if I have this HTML :"_ - then your shown selectors would not make much sense to begin, because every one of those `p` is the first, last and only child of its parent ...

Comment: If you actually had multiple `p` that _are_ siblings wrapped into two outer divs ... then you simply need to modify the numbers accordingly, add 1 to each: `div div p:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+6)`

Comment: Thank you for all your explanation CBroe, I edited again my message. And sorry for the incorrect message.

Comment: So you actually want to style everythning except the very first one, the nth-child stuff is a red herring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps something like this would work?

```
div div p:not(:first-child)
```

found in [Style every thing except first child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261508/style-every-thing-except-first-child)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? Where the first set isn't selected but the rest are?

```
div div:not(:first-child) p {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ktn9ga5e/1/)